# Add 2 Figures that each have a margin of error

Tags: arithmetic

How would I add two figures that each have a margin of error.

i.e.

3.5 +/- 10%

+

1.5 +/- 10%

With answer being the appropriate number with the appropriate margin of error.

Is the answer 5 +/- 10%?

How would you calculate it if the margin of error was different for each figure, i.e. 8% for the first figure and 3% for the second?